# How to get the number of dates of a specific Day Of the week in a List<DateTime>?

Tags: c#, lambda

Good day, I have a list, with some dates, I need to get The number of days of a day of the week, for example, get in a int variable the number of dates that are on Sunday, another int for Monday...

I've tried using the following code:

```
List<int> SundayDates = DateList.FindAll(x => x.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

but it says that it's read only, (And DateList, is the list where I storage my dates and where I want to get it).

Comment: Ok, so what is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: @Igor Well, I've tried using the following code: List<int> SundayDates = DateList.FindAll(x => x.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday) but it says that it's read only, (And DateList, is the list where I storage my dates and where I want to get it).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your attempt, the actual output, and the expected out. Also include any errors that you might have encountered including the compiler error or run time exception details.

Comment: You need to use `==`, that is for equality checking. A single `=` is an assignment.

Comment: Use Linq's [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count(v=vs.110).aspx) method.  Also make sure you use the _equality_ operator (`==`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You need to use `==`, that is for equality checking. A single `=` is an assignment
- To count the number of occurrences use [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
int numberOfSundays = DateList.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

---

Here is a count for each day of the week. The grouped join ensures that even if a day is not present in the list (example no occurrences of Monday) that it will still occur in the resulting list with a count of 0.

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EYEXQ3)

```
var DateList = new List<DateTime>(); // your populated list of dates

var allDaysOfWeek = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>();
var totalDayCounts = allDaysOfWeek.GroupJoin(DateList, dayOfWeek => dayOfWeek, date => date.DayOfWeek, (dayOfWeek, times) => new
{
    DayOfTheWeek = dayOfWeek,
    DayOfWeekCount = times.Count()
});
```

---

*do not forget to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file*